# How do I get <script type="module"> to use the given Authorization header?

Tags: html, http, basic-authentication

When loading a website with multiple `<script>` and `<script type="module">` declarations, the `Authorization:` header is applied for scripts but not for modules.

`<script src="lib/a-lib.js"></script>` works

`<script type="module" src="app/a-module.js"></script>` stucks with a 401.

Username/Password in the URL works too: `<script type="module" src="https://user:password@domain/app/a-module.js"></script>`. But since username:password are not converted to a Header, this is not a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just made a quick googling because it's quite interesting and found this:

> You can add credentials to a same-origin module by including the crossorigin attribute (which seems a bit weird to me, and I've questioned this in the spec). If you want to send credentials to other origins too, use crossorigin="use-credentials". Note that the other origin will have to respond with the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true header.

at [jake's site](https://jakearchibald.com/2017/es-modules-in-browsers/#no-credentials).

Hope it helps ;)

Comment: Indeed, it looks a bit weird. But it works. Thank you very much!